# write a sql query for below condition?

Tags: oracle

find out the 2nd most no. of employee working with dname from emp and dept table.

```
select d.dname,count(*) "totemp" from emp e,dept d
where e.deptno=d.deptno
group by (d.dname)
having count(*)=(select max(count(*)) from emp e,dept d 
where e.deptno=d.deptno
group by d.dname);
```

This query will show highest no. of employee working with dname.
But i want 2nd highest with dname.

Answer (score 0):

First use grouping to count employees for each dept, then use `dense_rank()` window function to assign rank values for dept groups and lastly select the dept which is ranked second.

```
select dname
from (
  select dname, dense_rank() over (order by cnt desc) as rnk
  from (
    select d.dname, count(*) as cnt
    from emp e
    join dept d using (deptno)
    group by d.dname
  ) t
) x
where rnk = 2
```

Using `dense_rank()` function you resolve ties properly, so if there are more than one depts with the same number of employees they will all pop up.

You can change your solution using `row_number()` function to pick any arbitrary dept even if there are ties on second position.

Comment: But here only dname is shown but i want dname with total no. of employee

Comment: add `cnt` column and it's all there.

Comment: union vs union all which gives more performance and why>

Comment: accept the answer if it helped you, Here's how: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Difference between UNION and UNION ALL is well described over the net